# how in SQL oracle 11g to get the result of one function in another?

Tags: sql, oracle

like this doesn't work

```sql
create FUNCTION getSomt RETURN sys_refcursor is
    vResult sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    open vResult for
        select 'Y' as field from dual;
    return vResult;
END getSomt;


create FUNCTION doWork RETURN sys_refcursor is
    vResult sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    open vResult for
        select * from getSomt() where field = 'N';
    return vResult;
END doWork;
```

Maybe something like using bulk collect? But I don't know how

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getSomt
  2     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  3  IS
  4     vResult  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  5  BEGIN
  6     OPEN vResult FOR SELECT 'Y' AS field FROM DUAL;
  7
  8     RETURN vResult;
  9  END getSomt;
 10  /

Function created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION doWork
  2     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  3  IS
  4     vResult  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  5  BEGIN
  6     vResult := getSomt;                   --> here
  7     RETURN vResult;
  8  END doWork;
  9  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT dowork FROM DUAL;

DOWORK
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

F
-
Y


SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT, based on your comment]**

If there's additional logic involved, you'll first have to **fetch** into locally declared variable(s), process the result, store it into another variable (I chose built-in `sys.odcivarchar2list` type as it suits this needs) and return the outcome.

The first function remains as it is (I added another row, with `N` field value):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getSomt
  2     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  3  IS
  4     vResult  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  5  BEGIN
  6     OPEN vResult FOR SELECT 'Y' AS field FROM DUAL
  7                      UNION ALL
  8                      SELECT 'N' FROM DUAL;
  9
 10     RETURN vResult;
 11  END getSomt;
 12  /

Function created.
```

`doWork` is significantly changed:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION doWork
  2     RETURN SYS.odcivarchar2list
  3  IS
  4     vResult  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  5     --
  6     l_field  VARCHAR2 (1);
  7     retval   SYS.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list ();
  8  BEGIN
  9     vResult := getSomt;
 10
 11     LOOP
 12        FETCH vResult INTO l_field;
 13
 14        EXIT WHEN vResult%NOTFOUND;
 15
 16        IF l_field = 'N'
 17        THEN
 18           retval.EXTEND;
 19           retval (retval.COUNT) := l_field;
 20        END IF;
 21     END LOOP;
 22
 23     RETURN retval;
 24  END doWork;
 25  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT dowork FROM DUAL;

DOWORK
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('N')

SQL>
```

Comment: the doWork function uses more complex logic than I gave above, I corrected the example. i.e. the result of doSomt will be processed as a SQL request

Comment: Have a look at edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the cursor using `XMLTYPE` and then parse it using `XMLTABLE` and use that to generate another cursor:

```sql
create FUNCTION getSomt RETURN sys_refcursor is
    vResult sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    open vResult for
        select 'Y' as field from dual UNION ALL
        select 'N' as field from dual;
    return vResult;
END getSomt;
/

create FUNCTION doWork RETURN sys_refcursor is
    vResult sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    open vResult for
        select *
        from   XMLTABLE(
                 'ROWSET/ROW'
                 PASSING XMLTYPE(getSomt())
                 COLUMNS
                   field VARCHAR2(1) PATH './FIELD'
                 
               )
        where  field = 'N';
    return vResult;
END doWork;
/
```

Then you can call it using:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_field VARCHAR2(1);
  v_cur   SYS_REFCURSOR := doWork();
BEGIN
  LOOP
    FETCH v_cur INTO v_field;
    EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_field);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> N
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gvAzkBMi)